# Optimizing insert operations in Python dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

If we have a situation where we want to insert an key, value in our dictionary only if key does not exists.
So in C++ we write like

```
auto it = my_dictionary.insert( std::make_pair( key , value ) );
```

and  later we can use the iterator for further comparisons like

```
if ( it->second < something ) { /* do something */ }
```

If we have to achieve same in Python, we do like..

```
if key not in my_dictionary:
     my_dictionary[key] = value
```

With every comparison or assignment, a look-up has to be performed. We are performing two searches in above code segments. How can we optimize this??

Comment: lookup in dictionary costs `O(1)` so don't worry too much.

Comment: Well, I was worried about birthday paradox.. as no hash implementation can be so perfect.

Comment: I am more concern about saving my search( same as C++ iterators), so that I can use the search result in next couple of steps for comparisons and updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of google search and discussion, I realized that this is the language design issue. Where references to successful search cannot be stored for future use.(i.e. I can't save an iterator or something like that).

If one needs a large dictionary, he should opt for C++.

Answer (score 1):

Python dictionaries work like hash tables. Every lookup you make is approximately constant time. There's no need to worry about performance in this case.

If you really want to save a kind of iterator to your dictionary you can use a dictionary and a list. Each key in the dictionary has an index of a list element, this is an example with a single element:

```
my_dictionary = dict(zip('key', 0))
actual_values = [value]
```

We get the correspondent key value by using the dictionary and then the list:

```
value = actual_values[my_dictionary['key']]
```

For the case you were asking it would be:

```
list_index = my_dictionary.get(key, None)
if list_index is not None:
    actual_values[list_index] = value
```

Now you're doing only one dictionary access, the other is a list indexing.

To show you that this is not worth worrying about. I computed the time difference between using the dictionary **1** time and then the array **n** times versus using the dictionary **n** times. Those are the results using `timeit` for a dictionary with 40000 keys:

```
╔═════╦══════════════╦═════════════╗
║  n  ║ Direct Index ║ Array Index ║
╠═════╬══════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 1   ║ 1.913920 s   ║ 2.012300 s  ║
║ 2   ║ 2.214828 s   ║ 2.035465 s  ║
║ 10  ║ 2.932283 s   ║ 2.600727 s  ║
║ 100 ║ 9.425869 s   ║ 8.032046 s  ║
╚═════╩══════════════╩═════════════╝
```

The performance gain you get is about 17% if you need to use the same key 100 times! Observe that if you use the dictionary just one time, the solution (array + dictionary) will actually be a bit worse, as expected. For the case you presented (n=2), your performance gain is of only 8%.

Remember, Python is not C or C++. If this is an actual performance issue for you, you shouldn't be using Python.

Comment: Well, I was worried about birthday paradox.. as no hash implementation can be so perfect for big hashes...

Answer (score 0):

Use setdefault:

```
v = my_dictionary.setdefault(key, value)
```